# Error installing package readtext in R studio

Tags: r, package

I am using R studio on Ubuntu and I need to install the package "readtext", though when I do the command to install it :

**install.packages("readtext")**

I get the following error :
ERROR: dependencies ‘pdftools’, ‘streamR’ are not available for package ‘readtext’
* removing ‘/home/ines/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.6/readtext’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘readtext’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/RtmpytIy3B/downloaded_packages’

Can you help me please?
Ines

Answer (score 1):

The [readtext package has a long list of Imports](https://cloud.r-project.org/web/packages/readtext/index.html).  Dependencies matter: you are will always be bound by the hardest constraint---which here appears to be that two of the listed direct `Imports:`.

Here I would recommend to work on the errors shown: as `readtext` depends on `pdftools` and `streamr`, you need to install these first.  So try to work out if

```
 install.packages("pdftools")
```

(which will likely require system dependency `libpoppler-cpp-dev` to be installed first via `sudo apt install libpoppler-cpp-dev`) and

```
 install.packages("streamR")
```

can be provided -- and then try `readtext`.

This is not an easy problem because of the many dependencies.  There are ways to install pre-built binaries from CRAN packages on Ubuntu, but that is another topic.